# Как отсечь запросы к api от других сайтов/устройств

Tags: php, api, безопасность

Имеется Api для моего сайта, написаное на php с протоколом http. 
Что-то вроде http://...ip.../events/?place=all&month=7

Cайт получает инфу в json(через api) из бд на серваке.

Работает отлично, но я задумался о защите. Не хочется чтобы кто-то тырил информацию, но я пока что не особо понимаю как правильно это сделать. Читал про токены, но хочу попросить объяснений или альтернатив (желательно не очень сложных, но стабильных). Конечный вопрос : как сделать так, чтобы только мой сайт мог пользоваться моим api. Заранее спасибо =)

Comment: Токены :) Всё верно, это самый лёгкий и безотказный вариант. CSRF-токен - это случайное значение, которое генерируется на сервере и передаётся клиенту, обычно в скрытом `input`. При запросе, клиент передаёт его в HTTP заголовке. Так сервер уверен, что общался именно с этим клиентом. Например, в Python Django эта защита реализована "из коробки".

Comment: Токен - это генератор случайных чисел (плюс время) -> пропускаем через один из извесных алгоритмов шифрования с ключём -> заворачиваем в base64. По идее билет (токен) подсмотреть можно, но он будет действителен... ну где-то час.

Comment: @nomnoms12 А можно поподробнее про CSRF-токен, кажется это действительно то что мне нужно) примерные Шаги использования? и могу ли я оставить http для этого)

Comment: @nick_n_a а как все это грамотно реализовать, можно поподробнее, времени на задачу мало остается)

Comment: CSRF токен можно тырить хоть каждый раз перед тем как делать запрос. Весь смысл в том, что при загрузке страницы вы генерируете токен на стороне сервера (на php).В токен помещается временная метка, можно time() после чего при каждом запросе к серверу используете этот токен, чтобы его не подделывали шифруете, потом при получения запроса расшифровываете токен и если временная метка актуальная - то разрешаете запрос.Но тут появляется ряд проблем для вас)Например, когда пользователь не обновял долго страницу и не получал актуальный токен) кому надо всё равно стырят это не сложно, не стоит того

Comment: @iproger вы хотите сказать что нет нормального способа не дать злоумышленникам подключаться к моему api?

Comment: Да. Вы можете ограничить API только от совсем слабых "злоумышленников". А школьники даже рады будут почувствовать себя хакерами обойдя ваш токен) Просто если у вас там по апи гуляет что то секретное, то значит стоит задуматься о правильности реализации. Вся логика должна быть на сервере. На клиенте только то, что вы готовы показать всем. Считайте, что браузер это злоумышленник, всё что видет браузер, то будут видеть все.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону jwt authentication + https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всегда можно подделать запросы и "стырить" инфу. API должно быть публичным и по безопасности рассчитано на то, что к нему имеют доступ все. Есть только способы усложнить этот процесс. Если придумать определенные способы шифрования и расшифровки данных (но алгоритм всегда можно увидеть в коде клиента и подключится к вашему API). Даже если вы придумаете супер сложное шифрование, то "стырить" инфу всё равно будет можно через JS-парсеры Selenium, CasperJs и тд.

Comment: Мне как раз нужно сделать этот сложнее. понятно что всегда найдется способ открыть сейф, хочу сделать просто проверку на подлинность места откуда пришел запрос)

Comment: Простой проверкой можете сделать просто API ключ. и HTTP_REFERER проверять, чтобы был только ваш сайт. То есть в идеале это таблица с api ключами и доступными доменами для этого апи ключа. Ключ передавать в шапке запроса. И на php проверять соовтествует ли referer данному ключ и есть ли вообще ключ.